# Does not have permission to access picker uri

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I open the image in the repository via Uri.

`var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }`

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract =
    ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
) { uri: Uri? ->
    imageUri = uri
}
```

`launcher.launch("image/*")`

After I transfer the picture via shared prefs, I switch to another screen, there is a picture on this screen, everything is OK. But, if I restart the application, I get an error.

[image]

```
 DatabaseUtils           com...ndroid.providers.media.module  E  Writing exception to parcel
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid ( 10192 ) does not have permission to access picker uri: content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000037
                                                                                                        at com.android.providers.media.PickerUriResolver.checkUriPermission(PickerUriResolver.java:294)
                                                                                                        at com.android.providers.media.PickerUriResolver.openTypedAssetFile(PickerUriResolver.java:118)
                                                                                                        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.openTypedAssetFileCommon(MediaProvider.java:8368)
                                                                                                        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.openTypedAssetFile(MediaProvider.java:8325)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:667)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:341)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1275)
```

I open the picture on another screen in this way:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = imageUri,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier)
```

Therefore, I conclude that if I need to get a picture in this way, I need to open the storage every time. This decision is extremely stupid, so I ask for advice :)

Comment: I think you are storing it in preferences as a uri correct? if so you need to store it as a file in the app storage then after that store the path to it in preferences that way you won't have a problem

Comment: Please no images. post the text from the logcat here as text.

Comment: `I open the picture on another screen`  You mean: in a different activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, if I restart the application, I get an error.

Yes. Why dont you mention the error?

After restart the permission to read the uri has gone.

To prevent this takePersistableUriPermission() in onActivityResult.;

Comment: okay, it's help. but I almost went crazy doing it. idk how to edit this.       
 @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedUri: Uri = data?.data ?: return

            val takeFlags = data.flags and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(selectedUri, takeFlags)


        }
    }

Comment: Please next time post your code in your post in a nice code block. Code as comment is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Decision :

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedUri: Uri = data?.data ?: return
            val takeFlags = data.flags and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(selectedUri, takeFlags)
        }
    }
```